# How do I create a database that receives data from other DBs, manual entry and data exports to create a web dashboard?

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, dashboard, metrics

I need to create a database which allow for easy manual entry of data as well as linking to SQL databases I have access to. This is something I've been researching and trying to design by myself for a while now. Everytime I think I have a solution I begin to have doubts that this is the right direction. I would really REALLY appreciate your help/input.

**My current workflow and nightmare.**
I work in IT and I'm responsible for reporting for my own group but it has been and will continue to expand across many groups across the whole IT organization. Each group has their own reporting tool with some that can export data cleanly/consistently, others that have to input data manually and a few which I can access the SQL database directly but haven't yet.

To create a monthly report I have a master workbook with graphs that reference data in multiple data collection workbooks. In these data collection workbooks I have the raw data which either myself or the team/service owners inputs each month. From that raw data I may create a pivot table to get the data I want and then in each one of the collection workbooks I have a 'reference" tab. In this reference tab I have a formula that is a rolling 13 months in the first column which say goes from Jan 2013 to Jan 2014. The months are calculated by referencing a cell that has the current reporting month in it. So for this example its Jan 2014. When you change that cell to the next month say Feb 2014 it will roll that first column so that those same cells now go from Feb 2013 to Jan 2014. the columns to the right of this column reference either the data table directly or the pivot tables using vlookups() or getpivotdata() formulas that reference the month cell to the left and grabs data accordingly. [Here is an example of a collection workbook.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14628356/NETWORKDATA.xlsx)

As you can see this can be a very manual and tedious workflow with many points where this could be improved. One major issue is the fact that each team/group doesn't pull data from the same tool and doesn't serve it up in the right format. I sometimes have to write a vba script to take the raw data and add helper data like a column with the correctly formatted 02/01/2014 format so it works in pivot tables correctly instead of multiple entries with different days (ie. 02/05/2014 02/23/2014).

**The end goal + where I want to be**
I want to create a database where I can link SQL databases directly to it as well as making it easy for a team to manually input data by reading in a csv or xls file of data. The crux again is that I'm only one person and I want to offload as much as the data entry to each one of those teams/groups without making it a difficult task.

Using the master sheet to create a monthly report has some great results but I would like this to be a web accessible and dynamic dashboard. I'm a pretty good front end dev with knowledge of HTML, CSS+LESS and some JS+SQL knowledge. I will have support of a senior web developer if I can proceed with this project. I just need help in working out the data collection/storage/querying portion of this.

If you got this far thank you so much for reading about my problem. If I wasn't clear about something or you have more questions for me please feel free to ask.

THANKS!

Comment: Pay for the full version of Microsoft's latest SQL Server and it has all kinds of data transform stuff that I doubt you're going to get in your free MySQL.  I love MySQL (I much prefer it) but for all the user-centric stuff you want, its not the way to go. MySQL is more developer-centric.

Comment: Oracle XE is a freeware version of Oracle's 11g database.  It doesn't need a server grade os to install and it also comes out of the box with [Application Express](http://apex.oracle.com), a browser based development tool with other useful features such as the data workbench which provides a means of uploading text files of data in varying formats for direct import to the database tables you create.  The Apex home page also offers hosted instances if you don't have time to download and install.  That should give you an idea if the tool and the db may be a good fit for you.

Comment: Thanks you two for the answers. I believe I have licensing to create an instance of either SQL server or Oracle 11g. I guess I'll have to research how the workflow would be for inputting data from text files or csv files and how I would get this data formatted correctly for input. Cheers for pointing me in the right direction as I'm not a back-end DB admin expert!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at SQL Server's [linked servers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx), according to the documentation, you can link any database who have an OLE DB driver so you can run queries mixing SQL Server and other databases, so it may be worth your while to check this.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was told about linked servers and I appreciate the suggestion. I think I will definitely do this for some of the data. I suppose the part I'm left with is I'm not sure how I'll input data from CSV or XLS into the DB.

Comment: I take that back. I guess I can import CSV files into the DB and set a schedule to do this.